# Regex allowing white space, characters and numbers

Tags: html, regex

I am having problem with some regex expression, I need a regex to check whether the field is blank or not, if blank it should show a message "This field is required".

I tried this regex but it doesn't work.

```
allRules =  {"required":{
                        "regex":"none",
                        "alertText":"* This field is required",
                        "alertTextCheckboxMultiple":"* Please select an option",
                        "alertTextCheckboxe":"* This checkbox is required"},
```

It somehow only works only on textfield not textarea. Anyone can solve this? Thanks

UPDATE: Also, it must allow special chracters as such , and .

Comment: I don't see any regular expression. What you posted is definitely not a regular expression. Is this some configuration for a JavaScript form validation tool?

Comment: My bad, for the words only I managed to do <code>/^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/</code>

UPDATE : @FelixKling yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/^$/` matches an empty string. The opposite, to check if a string is non-empty, is `/./`

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem. 1 more thing, how to check whether combobox is not empty?

Comment: HTML doesn't have comboboxes. If you are referring to a dropdown (`<select>`), then I guess it's empty if the value of the selected entry is empty.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I tried using same regex it works but a few problem though, I used my own regex works well too.